# How to use a button to move only the first item in a listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, listbox

I have two list boxes and an ASP button. I am trying to use the button to move only the first item in the index of one list box to the other. Unfortunately whenever the button is pushed, it either moves all of the items in the list box or moves the first one in the index as many times as there are items (for example: if there are five items in the list box, it will move the first item to the next list box 5 times. so i have no items in the first list box and five of the first item in the next list box.) Also, the list boxes are in an Ajax update panel (I don't know if that is relevant). Here is the code:

```
protected void btnMoveFirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.Items[0]);
        }

        for (int i = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.Items[0]);
        }  
    }
```

Comment: You want to move the first item where? which position you'd like to move?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this code

```
protected void btnMoveFirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            //Add items only once
            ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.Items[0]);  
            ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.Items[0]);
    }
```

In your code you are adding item till the count of items in `ListBox1`

```
       for (int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.Items[0]);
        }
```

That's why it is adding your items more number of times

Comment: Thanks. I feel so silly because I was making too complicated.

Comment: @KelliDavis its ok it happens somtime.. :)